# Error 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, dll

I found this error [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application when i run this python command *windll.LoadLibrary("C:\Windows\System32\plcommpro.dll")*
For this error i found my plcommpro.dll file is not executable file.But I don't know how to make it as a executable file.If someone knows please share me.
Thanks and Best.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a 32 bit Python and the DLL is a 64 bit DLL you will get this error, likewise if the DLL is 32 bit and your Python is 64 bit.

You can check this using the `dumpbin /HEADERS <dll filepath>` command from a visual studio command prompt.

Comment: my python version is 2.7.12 MSC v.1500 64 bit(AMD64) on win 32