# error 193 -is-not-a-valid-win32 application

Tags: python, anaconda

I get this error running this app

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "LinkedInEasyApply.py", line 221, in 
driver = init_driver()
File "LinkedInEasyApply.py", line 34, in init_driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "./chromedriver")
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in init
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in init
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

https://github.com/udaybhaskar578/LinkedIn-Easy-Apply-Automation

i am using python 2.7 through anaconda on win 64 bit version and cant figure out how to fix this

[Error 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477956/error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

this did not help